# Difference between inserting a DOM element into a variable and using it's properties, and doing the same without a variable

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm trying to create a JS calculator.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input"></div>
    <button class="num" id="num1">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="num2">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="num3">3</button>
    <button class="num" id="num4">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="num5">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="num6">6</button>
    <button class="num" id="num7">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="num8">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="num9">9</button>
    <button class="num" id="num0">0</button>
    <button class="equal">=</button>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
    <button class="minus">-</button>
  </div>
```

I just began to write code that will display the numbers that were clicked and was wondering why this code works:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.querySelector('.input').textContent += el.textContent;
      })
    })
```

While this code doesn't:

```
var value = document.querySelector('.input').textContent;
    document.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        value += el.textContent;
      })
    })
```

Aren't they the same? The only difference is that in the second example a variable holds the querySelector and the textContent property.

Comment: Adding a sample of the HTML would improve the quality of the question.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = document.querySelector('.input').textContent;
```

That line does not do what you think it does. It does not store a reference to the element's text content in the variable `value`; instead, it stores the *value*. It's a string. In JavaScript, strings are immutable, meaning you can't change them once they're created. When you do something  like `value += 'hello'` you're actually creating a new string with the appended characters, while the original remains unchanged.

What you want to be doing instead is storing a reference to the DOM element itself so you can assign new values to its textContent in the loop:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.input');
document.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    element.textContent += el.textContent;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are primitive data types and so when you do this:

```
var value = document.querySelector('.input').textContent;
```

value is just what was the textContent, it doesn't contain the reference to it. If you want to do something like this you would probably structure it like so:

```
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
document.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        input.textContent += el.textContent;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a reference; updating it won't update the `textContent` property of your element. You *could* do something like:

```
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.input');
document.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    inputElement.textContent += el.textContent;
  })
})
```

For more information, see:

- [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/1810460)
- [JavaScript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/1810460)